# How to repeat a function with a different value?

Tags: core-language

What is the best way to generate ten Taylor Polynomials for n=1 to n=10 of a function, say $\cos(x)$?

```
Normal[Series[Cos[x], {x, 0, 1}]]
```

This will give me the right answer for n=1 ($P_1$), but I am looking for a way to "automatically" generate $P_1$ to $P_{10}$

Comment: You are in for a treat with `Table` or `Map` (just to name two obvious candidates).

Comment: @YvesKlett I don't fully see how I should  apply Map in this case. Can you enlighten me?

Comment: `(Normal[Series[Cos[x], {x, 0, #}]] & /@ Range[10]) // TableForm` Get rid of `//TableForm` if you want to use it for anything. That's just to make the output look nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have an Solution for [Map](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) i.e. [Applying Functions to Lists](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ApplyingFunctionsToLists.html) here is one with [Table](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html)

```
Table[Normal[Series[Cos[x], {x, 0, i}]], {i, 10}]
```

> $\left\{1,1-\frac{x^2}{2},1-\frac{x^2}{2},\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^2}{2}+1,\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^2}{2}+1,-\frac{x^6}{720}+\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^2}{2}+1,-\frac{x^6}{720}+\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^2}{2}+1,\frac{x^8}{40320}-\frac{x^6}{720}+\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^2}{2}+1,\frac{x^8}{40320}-\frac{x^6}{720}+\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^2}{2}+1,-\frac{x^{10}}{3628800}+\frac{x^8}{40320}-\frac{x^6}{720}+\frac{x^4}{24}-\frac{x^2}{2}+1\right\}$

TableForm works as well:

```
TableForm[%]
```

[image]